# Reqests.get take many time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, get, load

This code has become time-consuming, but it used to do it very quickly

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import requests

wb = load_workbook(r"C:\TranslateMfestSite\ProductsInformation.xlsx")

sheet=wb['Sheet']
Designer=551
 
for i in range(1, 14498):
    if int(sheet["C"+str(i)].value)==Designer and 'xlink:href="' in requests.get(str(sheet["B"+str(i)].value)).text:
        r = requests.get(str(sheet["B"+str(i)].value)).text
```

Comment: If this is not performing well it's likely to be due to the HTTP request (server side is slow). You are making two GET requests for the same URL in your loop. Why? Have you considered multithreading?

Answer (score 0):

This code is not written very well.

Start with rewriting for readability:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import requests

workbook = load_workbook(r"C:\TranslateMfestSite\ProductsInformation.xlsx")

sheet=workbook['Sheet']
designer=551
 
for i in range(1, 14498):
    response = requests.get(
        str(sheet["B"+str(i)].value)
    ).text
    
    if int(sheet["C"+str(i)].value)==designer and 'xlink:href="' in response:
        r = response
```

we can see that you were calling a single rest call just to check if it had some properties and then called it again - this is bad.

But there is more work to do here! One of your logic checks has NOTHING to do with the rest call - so you may be wasting many calls to this endpoint - so instead invalidate on that condition first!

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import requests

workbook = load_workbook(r"C:\TranslateMfestSite\ProductsInformation.xlsx")

sheet=workbook['Sheet']
designer=551
 
for i in range(1, 14498):
    if int(sheet["C"+str(i)].value)!=designer:
        continue

    response = requests.get(
        str(sheet["B"+str(i)].value)
    ).text
    
    if 'xlink:href="' in response:
        r = response
```

Now... that cleared it up a bit. But I am wondering... What is r = response? Is that terminal? Once it is set, now what?

Let's assume it isn't, let's clean it up more - the iteration is messy

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import requests

workbook = load_workbook(r"C:\TranslateMfestSite\ProductsInformation.xlsx")

sheet=workbook['Sheet']
designer=551

for B, C in sheet.iter_rows(max_row=1 max_row=14498, min_col=2, max_col=3):
    if C.value != designer:
        continue

    response = requests.get(
        str(B.value)
    ).text
    
    if 'xlink:href="' in response:
        r = response
```

Now this code is cleaner, clearer, and you can see what it is doing. It has removed extra REST calls. Now what remains is whether the code should exit - or not...

Answer (score 0):

If every row in the spreadsheet has a value equal to DESIGNER then you'll be making over 14,000 HTTP GET requests. That's probably not the case. However, doing this synchronously is never likely to perform well.

Multithreading is useful for scenarios such as this.

Let's use multithreading where the thread builds a global dictionary keyed on the URL extracted from the B column of the spreadsheet and its associated value is the text acquired from URL

**Note:** This is untested (for obvious reasons)

```
import requests
import openpyxl
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

WORKBOOK = r"C:\TranslateMfestSite\ProductsInformation.xlsx"
SHEET = 'Sheet'
DESIGNER = 551
B, C = 1, 2

results = {}
wb = None

def get_text(url):
    print(f'{url=}')
    try:
        with requests.get(url) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            results[url] = response.text
    except Exception:
        pass

try:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(WORKBOOK)
    ws = wb[SHEET]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as tpe:
        for row in ws.iter_rows():
            if len(row) > 2 and int(row[C].value) == DESIGNER:
                tpe.submit(get_text, str(row[B].value))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    if wb:
        wb.close()

for url, text in results.items():
    print(url, text)
```